# Count visitor with same id but different name and show it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1','2','2','3','3','4','4'],
                    'name': ['James','Jim','jimy','Daniel','Dane','Ash','Ash'],
                    'event': ['Basket','Soccer','Soccer','Basket','Soccer','Basket','Soccer']})
```

I want to count unique values of id but with the name, the result I except are:

```
id name         count   
1  James          1       
2  Jim, jimy      2
3  Daniel, Dane   2
4  Ash            2
```

I try to group by id and name but it doesn't count as i expected

Comment: Show us the code that you're using to count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```py
df1.groupby('id').agg(
    name=('name', lambda x: ', '.join(x.unique())),
    count=('name', 'count')
)
```

We are basically grouping by `id` and then joining the unique `names` to a comma separated list!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```py
groups = df1[["id", "name"]].groupby("id")
a = groups.agg(lambda x: ", ".join( set(x) ))
b = groups.size().rename("count")
c = pd.concat([a,b], axis=1)
```

I'm not an expert when it comes to pandas but I thought I might as well post my solution because I think that it's straightforward and readable.

In your example, the groupby is done on the `id` column and not by `id` and `name`. The `name` column you see in your expected DataFrame is the result of an aggregation done after a groupby.
Here, it is obvious that the groupby was done on the `id` column.

My solution is maybe not the most straightforward but I still find it to be more readable:

1. Create a groupby object `groups` by grouping by `id`
2. Create a DataFrame `a` from `groups` by aggregating it using commas (you also need to remove the duplicates using `set(...)` ): `lambda x: ", ".join( set(x) )`

The DataFrame `a` will thus have the following data:

```
            name
id
1          James
2      Jim, jimy
3   Daniel, Dane
4            Ash
```

3. Create another DataFrame `b` by computing the size of each groups in `groups` : `groups.size()` (you should also rename your column)

```
id
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

4. Concat `a` and `b` horizontally and you get what you wanted

```
            name  count
id
1          James      1
2      Jim, jimy      2
3   Daniel, Dane      2
4            Ash      2
```